# iMask Vue.js 2 returning value error: value should be string"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, imaskjs

I'm using the pattern mask, I have iMask imported. Here's a snippet. Vue 2. iMask v 6.6.1

```
        <AIOInputLabel id="interestRate" :disable="isDisabledFormControl('interestRate')" :icon="interestRate.icon" :iconPercent="interestRate.iconPercent" :isPercent="interestRate.isPercent" :label="interestRate.label" :placeholder="interestRate.placeholder" :type="interestRate.type" :value.sync="interestRate.value" v-bind:class = "(isDisabledFormControl('interestRate'))?'noborder':currentClassIR" />
```

I have type set to text,

and using simple guide code for mask pattern in my mounted() function

```
IMask(document.getElementById("interestRate"), { mask: '0[00][.][000]', lazy: true, placeholder: '0' });
```

I get the following Error

```
[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "Error: value should be string"
```

secondary error : Error: value should be string

my interestRate variable is an imported value with the following values,

```
    const InterestRate = {
  label: "Interest Rate",
  placeholder: "0.000",
  value: "",
  type: "text",
  icon: false,
  pattern: "#.###",
  iconPercent: true,
    isPercent: true
};
```

Not exactly sure where to look for a solution, I have checked the iMask.js github repository, and there are some issues that relate using angular, i'm obviously using Vue but the solution presented doesn't seem to fix my problem.

Comment: I located an area of my code that was converting the value to a number in my beforeMount() option. i changed that to a .toString() function and it converted it to a string. I checked by logging typeof and yet the error is still persisting in the console.